# Import a graph (network) in Julia

Tags: julia, graph-tool, lightgraphs

Does anybody now if there is any module that could let me import a graph (network) in Julia?

Working with Python, I used the graph-tool package, which served me very well! I have my graphs in .gt file format. Can I use any module in Julia, so that I can import them there?

I have searched for LightGraphs and Junet, which is fairly new but cannot seem to see any "import" section in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to convert your `gt` files to `graphml` format, which is compatible with LightGraphs, and is [the recommended alternative format by graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#graph-i-o).

---

Suppose you have a ".gt" file that was generated in the past by the following python code:

```python
from graph_tool.all import *
g = Graph()
v1 = g.add_vertex()
v2 = g.add_vertex()
e = g.add_edge(v1,v2)
g.save('g.gt')
```

Start a new python session, and convert from "gt" to "graphml" format:

```python
import graph_tool as gt
g = gt.Graph()
g.load('g.gt')
g.save('g.xml.gz')
```

Then, in julia, use `LightGraphs` with the `GraphIO` package to load from the GraphML file:

```julia
using LightGraphs, GraphIO
D = loadgraphs("g.xml.gz", GraphMLFormat())
#> Dict{String,LightGraphs.AbstractGraph} with 1 entry:
#   "G" => {2, 1} directed simple Int64 graph
```

---

If you'd like to use `PyCall` to perform the conversion directly from within julia (i.e. in a script), here's how:

```julia
using PyCall
@pyimport graph_tool as gt
G = gt.Graph()
G[:load]("g.gt")
G[:save]("g.xml.gz")
```

(Note that this implies python and the graph-tool library are already installed on your machine and accessible from julia).

---

In theory, if you prefer graph-tools and you're used to its syntax and wish to keep working directly with the `.gt` file format, you *can* use it via PyCall from within julia throughout as above. Whether this is preferable to migrating over to LightGraphs which is *designed* for julia though is another thing. It's your call :)

---

<sub>PS. Greetings from Leamington, fellow Leamingtonian!</sub>

Comment: How could I not see that? That was more than just informative! Thank you very much for your help!

I will think I'll go with the first one, as the graph-tool is not installed on my local machine (I am mostly working via server)

PS My greetings to you as well, fellow Leamingtonian!

Answer (score 1):

Graph importing for LightGraphs is now in [GraphIO.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/GraphIO.jl). Supported import formats currently include

- GML
- Graph6
- GEXF
- GraphML
- Pajek NET
- DOT

with more formats coming soon.